# Find all the nodes which can be reached from a given node within certain distance

Tags: algorithm, search, breadth-first-search

Multiple nodes can also be traversed in sequence to create a path.

```
struct Node {
  float pos [2];
  bool visited = false;
};

// Search Space
Node nodes [MAX_NODE_COUNT];

// Function to return all reachable nodes
// nodeCount : Number of nodes
// nodes : Array of nodes
// indexCount : Size of the returned array
// Return : Returns array of all reachable node indices
int* GetReachableNodes (int nodeCount, Node* nodes, int* indexCount)
{
   // This is the naive approach
   queue <int> indices;
   vector <int> indexList;
   indices.push (nodes [0]);
   nodes [0].visited = true;

   // Loop while queue is not empty
   while (!indices.empty ())
   {
     // Pop the front of the queue
     int parent = indices.front ();
     indices.pop ();
     // Loop through all children
     for (int i = 0; i < nodeCount; ++i)
     {
       if (!nodes [i].visited && i != parent && DistanceSqr (nodes [i], nodes [parent]) < maxDistanceSqr)
       {
         indices.push (i);
         nodes [i].visited = true;
         indexList.push_back (i);
       }
     }
   }
   int* returnData = new int [indexList.size ()];
   std::move (indexList.begin (), indexList.end (), returnData);
   *indexCount = indexList.size ();
   // Caller responsible for delete
   return returnData;
}
```

The problem is I can't use a graph since all nodes are connected to each other.
All the data is just an array of nodes with their positions and the start node.

I can solve this problem easily with BFS but it's n^2.
I have been figuring out how to solve this in less than O(n^2) time complexity.

Some of the approaches I tried were parallel BFS, Dijkstra but it doesn't help a lot.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Why would you need to create a path when all the nodes are connected to each other?

Comment: Because if the distance between two nodes is greater than a certain value, we are not allowed to traverse from one to other.

Comment: I am not seeing any good algorithm other than BFS. You need to find all nodes within certain distance, so its kind of exhaustive search to certain level of BFS

Comment: Sounds like [space partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning#Types_of_space-partitioning_data_structures) to me.

Comment: If you mean n is the number of nodes, then the problem is Omega(n^2)  because a completely connected graph has Omega(n^2) edges, and in general you'll need to inspect all edges. So you can stop looking for a better algorithm.

Comment: "All the data is just an array of nodes with their positions and the start node." Either the thinking half of my brain suddenly shut down or this explanation makes no sense. Position where? How about you edit your Q and make clear what data structures you have and what meaning have the values you deal with.?

Comment: I have edited the question so you can get a better idea. I think Space Partitioning is the way to go.